# Get defined name in excel worksheet from passing range

Tags: excel, delphi-2007

I'm trying to populate an excel file using defined names. What I like to do now is that once I move to a cell e.g. Worksheet1!$A$8, I want to retrieve the defined name for that cell which tells me what is the data needed. Right now this is what I got and only give me ....$A$8, what I expect is PROD_CATEGORY as this is what I defined the name to be for that cell.  Really appreciate if anyone can help.

```
WorkSheet.Range[ColNumToAlpha(CurrCol)+IntToStr(HRow)].Name
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will return all the range names containing the range you pass to the function. You could, for instance, pass `WorkSheet.Range[ColNumToAlpha(CurrCol)+IntToStr(HRow)]` to this function.

```
Function TellNamedRanges(ByVal Target As Range) As String
  Dim NamedRange As Name
  Dim FoundOne As Boolean
  Dim RangesFound As String

  FoundOne = False
  RangesFound = "Found these ranges: "

  For Each NamedRange In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(NamedRange.RefersTo)) Is Nothing Then
      FoundOne = True
      RangesFound = RangesFound & NamedRange.Name & " "
    End If
  Next NamedRange

  If FoundOne = False Then
    TellNamedRanges = RangesFound & "none found"
  Else
    TellNamedRanges = RangesFound
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is gold. I used this to comeup with similar coding in delphi. now the problem is if the target doesn't have a name defined my code crashes, any idea on how to check it select range is named?

Comment: I designed this to return information "none found" if Target does not exist in any named range, but of course this is not a valid range address. Do you maybe need to handle that?

Comment: I thought i didn't but looking at the files, I do need to. So all I want to check is the pass target has a name

Comment: It's easy enough to modify the return to suit. Let me know if you need more help.